# Android - Radius server PEAP authentication

Tags: android, radius

One my Android device is correctly authenticated on Radius server, but second one my device with Android 6 has problem authenticate through FreeRadius server.
The problem is, that instead of Identity(what means user name) send to the server MAC address.

On router I see:

**12:54:45 radius,debug,packet     User-Name = "00:01:02:03:04:05"**

should be

***12:54:45 radius,debug,packet     User-Name = "zajdan"***

Radius server log:

**Tue Jan 17 11:52:30 2017 : Auth: Login incorrect: 00:01:02:03:04:05/00:01:02:03:04:05]**

Has anybody same problem, that instead of User-name / Identity is passed MAC address?

Thank You
ZAJDAN